# Is it better to make a GIF out of a JPG or PNG?

Tags: png, file-size, animated-gif, jpeg

I started with two PNGs. Their sizes were 296 KB and 222 KB.
Then I converted the two PNGs to JPGs using Paint 3D, and their sizes were reduced to 189 KB and 164 KB.

I made animated GIFs out of both sets of images, and the GIF made from the larger PNGs took up less space than the ones made from the JPGs. The difference was 12.6 KB vs 13.2 KB.

1. Why is that?
2. Is there a best practice to use one method over the other?

Comment: File size is not always the determining factor. The formats, especially gif, have specific limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why your animated gifs varied by **600 bytes** is hard to say. It's a minuscule amount and *could* be attributed to something as simple as anti-aliasing variations or dithering differences.

---

More information about image formats and choosing the proper one...

File *size* is often *less* of a concern than **usability**. In most instances one chooses the *format* that is suitable for the desired use, and *then* tries to get file size to a minimum. It's rare that file size *dictates* format. Format limitations have to be considered *first*.

- **GIF** is an **indexed** color mode. It doesn't allow smooth color. Color transitions, at best, have to be **dithered** - that is when you see pixels spreading like dots to blend between two colors. While GIF *does* support transparency, it does *not* allow for smooth color transitions within the image. If you need smooth color transitions, GIF is most often the wrong format. **The GIF format is great for images with minimal colors and hard color edges.** In addition, The GIF format **allows for *animation*** within the image itself. JPG and PNG8/24/32 do *not* allow for animation.
- **JPG** *does* allow for **smooth color transitions** and is a *compressed* format. But it's ***lossy***. Lossy means, the format *throws away data* in an effort to minimize file size. You can see this when you open a JPG and then save it as a JPG again. Each subsequent save will *degrade* the image and introduce *artifacts* where the format has thrown away data. JPG also does *not* support any transparency. So, if you need transparency, JPG is just the incorrect format to use. **The JPG format is great for images that don't need any transparency and need colors to transition smoothly within the image itself.**
- **PNG** is a mix of both of the above. All PNG options *do* allow for **transparency**. But there are variations within the PNG format.

  - **PNG8** is pretty much like a GIF *minus* the animation functionality, PNG8 an **indexed** color mode and does *not* allow for smooth color transitions. 
    -- The PNG8 format.. well.. to be honest.. I've *never* used it. GIFs are typically smaller in file size and PNG8 doesn't really offer any benefit over GIF that I'm aware of.
  - **PNG24** or **PNG32** *do* allow for **smooth color transitions**, in *addition to supporting **transparency***. PNG24/32 is somewhat like a JPG + transparency. But PNG is a *lossless* format. PNGs will *not* "throw out data" to reduce the file size. PNGs *can* be slightly larger in terms of file size because the format is a lossless format.
    -- **The PNG24/32 format is a great format for when one needs smooth color transitions *and* transparency.**

So, which format you choose depends on the image itself and the necessary usage **then** file size is addressed.

There is **no one "best" format**. Each format serves a purpose. Which one you use depends upon your purpose *and* the nature of the image itself.

---

<sub>There is also **aPNG** which is similar to **PNG24/32 + animation**. Support for aPNG has been somewhat slow to take hold. [aPNG is largely supported in all browsers ***except Internet Explorer***.](https://caniuse.com/apng) The problem is that IE is still a *major staple of Windows users* and without IE support, the usefulness of aPNG drops considerably. That is unless specific fallbacks are in place for aPNG images in IE.</sub>

---

Answer (score 2):

Jpeg uses a compression that is based on what the whole image looks like. Thus changes the whole image slightly this works well for photographs but not ideal fror drawn pictures. This is why jpeg is called a lossy format, something gets lost.

While PNG does no changes to the image or when it does do changes they work like GIF changes would work.

So yes i expect PNG to work better.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends whether you want to have a GIF with transparent areas (like often used in Instagram stories) JPEG doesn't feature transparent parts. However PNG does.